# How to change django base class's related_name?

Tags: django, django-models

I am stuck in this condition:

I have two different relation point to the same model, so I have to give the m2m field a related_name.

```py
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    b_m2m = models.ManyToManyField(B, verbose_name='additional_a',
                                              blank=True, related_name="additional_a_group")
```

It works well until I want to inherit it

```py
class ABase(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    b_m2m = models.ManyToManyField(B, verbose_name='additional_a',
                                              blank=True, related_name="additional_a_group")
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class A(ABase):
    pass

class C(ABase):
    pass
```

Now the problem is, B's reverse relation to both A and C have the same related_name `additional_a_group` and I do not know how to resolve it.

If I remove the related_name in ABase, b and b_m2m will conflict.
However, if I leave it here, A and C will conflict.

I looked back into source code, `related_name` is used by `ManyToManyRel.get_accessor_name`. Maybe I could resolve it by overwrite both `ManyToManyField` and `ManyToManyRel`, but is there something easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### it needs to generate two different related_names.

```
b_m2m = models.ManyToManyField(
    B, 
    verbose_name='additional_a',
    blank=True, 
    related_name="%(class)s_additional_a_group"
)
```

Comment: thanks, I forgot the syntax in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name